# Unlist a list within a list of data.frames into a single data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
dat <- list(list(structure(list(ID = 1, Gender = structure(1L, .Label = "Male", class = "factor"), 
    Phrase = structure(1L, .Label = "Hello", class = "factor"), 
    Phrase2 = structure(1L, .Label = "Goodbye", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Gender", "Phrase", "Phrase2"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(ID = 1, Gender = structure(1L, .Label = "Female", class = "factor"), 
        Phrase = structure(1L, .Label = "Good afternoon", class = "factor"), 
        Phrase2 = structure(1L, .Label = "Goodbye", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
    "Gender", "Phrase", "Phrase2"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")), 
    list(structure(list(ID = 2, Gender = structure(1L, .Label = "Male", class = "factor"), 
        Phrase = structure(1L, .Label = "Hello", class = "factor"), 
        Phrase2 = structure(1L, .Label = "Good afternoon", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
    "Gender", "Phrase", "Phrase2"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(ID = 2, Gender = structure(1L, .Label = "Female", class = "factor"), 
            Phrase = structure(1L, .Label = "Goodbye", class = "factor"), 
            Phrase2 = structure(1L, .Label = "Goodbye", class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
        "Gender", "Phrase", "Phrase2"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
        ), class = "data.frame")))

> dat
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
  ID Gender Phrase Phrase2
1  1   Male  Hello Goodbye

[[1]][[2]]
  ID Gender         Phrase Phrase2
1  1 Female Good afternoon Goodbye


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  ID Gender Phrase        Phrase2
1  2   Male  Hello Good afternoon

[[2]][[2]]
  ID Gender  Phrase Phrase2
1  2 Female Goodbye Goodbye
```

I have a list of data.frames called `dat`, in which within each list element, there are multiple entries (e.g. by Gender). How can I combine this list of data.frames into a single data.frame that looks like this?

```
  ID Gender         Phrase        Phrase2
1  1   Male          Hello        Goodbye
2  1 Female Good afternoon        Goodbye
3  2   Male          Hello Good afternoon
4  2 Female        Goodbye        Goodbye
```

I have tried `ldply(dat, data.frame)`, `do.call("rbind", dat)`, and `rbind.fill(dat)` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(dat, bind_rows)
# ID Gender         Phrase        Phrase2
#1 1   Male          Hello        Goodbye
#2  1 Female Good afternoon        Goodbye
#3  2   Male          Hello Good afternoon
#4  2 Female        Goodbye        Goodbye
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) package.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% flatten() %>% bind_rows()
#   ID Gender         Phrase        Phrase2
# 1  1   Male          Hello        Goodbye
# 2  1 Female Good afternoon        Goodbye
# 3  2   Male          Hello Good afternoon
# 4  2 Female        Goodbye        Goodbye
```